# Installing body-parser node.js fail

Tags: node.js, body-parser

taso5@taso5-SATELLITE-L775-15T:~$ sudo npm install body-parser
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "body-parser"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: body-parser@undefined1.15.2
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 1.15.2, 1.15.1, 1.15.0, 1.14.2, 1.14.1, 1.14.0, 1.13.3, 1.13.2, 1.13.1, 1.13.0, 1.12.4, 1.12.3, 1.12.2, 1.12.1, 1.12.0, 1.11.0, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.3, 1.9.2, 1.9.1, 1.9.0, 1.8.4, 1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.7, 1.6.6, 1.6.5, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Did :
sudo npm install -g npm@latest 
npm@3.10.9

sudo npm install -g
freeze and do nothing

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo with npm

Comment: I get permission denied if I don't.